# How to download firmware for Macbook 2017 sound card?

Tags: linux, drivers, pureos

Currently I am trying to find firmware for a MacBook 2017 sound card.
The specific type of card I have is a Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP HD Audio.

I am running PureOS. PureOs seems to detect that I have *a* sound card, but no sound is coming out. I have run `speaker-test`.

Comment: If you can see that you have a sound card, congratulations, you have drivers. Also, the number of things where you could "download" drivers for is... low on modern linuxes.

Comment: Oh. Maybe I’m muted or something. And by see I mean it shows up on commands like `lspci`, etc.

Comment: Linux doesn't have a concept of drivers per se, everything is normally included in the kernel. As to why you've got no audio with your kernel - you need to Google for it. Maybe try a less obscure distro and something more supported, i.e. Fedora 36. Why people continue to insist on some strange Linux distros only to have issues with them is beyond me.

Comment: `lspci` sees anything that's on a supported PCI-like bus, regardless of whether there is a driver for it or not. What other commands does your sound card show up in?
Also, quick googling indicates you might need kernel version 5.17 or above to have a chance to get working sound on Macbook 2017; DistroWatch tells me PureOS 10 apparently has kernel version 5.10.46 which seems too old.